# Have something ready VS. Prepare somthing

Tags: meaning

What's the difference?

> Have your vaccination card ready.

> Prepare your vaccination card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Have your card ready* is usually a reminder that the card will shortly be required for inspection, so you should search for it among your belongings and have it in your hand. This is the idiomatic expression.

*Prepare your card* sounds like a request to do something to the card - to 'make it ready' rather than 'have it ready'.